# Linux wget -O /dev/null <http....> syntax

Tags: linux, cron, wget

At my job we have a Linux server with several cron jobs with the syntax `wget -O /dev/null` followed immediately by an `http` request to a `PHP` file or whatever. So something like `wget -O /dev/null "http://foo.bar.com/file.php"`.

I've been able to find out what the various pieces of it mean individually:

- `wget`: An app that can be used in the Linux terminal to download files from web resources without a GUI. If you have the URL to a particular download, like WordPress, PyCharm, whatever, you can use -wget to download it without physically visiting the site.
- `wget -O`: The `-O` option allows you to rename the file you're downloading. So if I was downloading VS Code but wanted to rename it, I could run `wget -O <alternate name> <url to vscode download file>`.
- `dev/null`: From what I understand, this is basically a dump for unwanted log files. If a program is running from the Terminal, and you don't care to see/store the output, you can direct it here, where it will be immediately and automatically erased. Basically a way to save space for large programs.

I just can't figure out what they do together - Does using them all together rename the `PHP` file to `/dev/null` so Linux catches it and erases it? Is this some sort of shorthand syntax to rename the file to an empty string, and direct the results to `/dev/null?`. Or more likely something different that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems it periodically "pings" server with GET request. Maybe a kind of watchdog to let server know that host is alive or to notifiy server with self external IP address.

Comment: I'm not sure that that's what's going on, because the script is actually being run as a result of this cron job. I would fiddle with it and test it myself but it's not exactly something I can safely mess with.

Comment: So what is unclear with the command? `wget -O /dev/null "http://foo.bar.com/file.php"` makes HTTP GET request to specified URL, receives response and discards it. What purpose of that request? My guess is that it's for acknowledge the server that host is alive. I think exact answer hides in `file.php` on the server. If you don't have access to the server, you can try at least save response with `wget "http://foo.bar.com/file.php` or open this URL in browser and look what is in response, maybe there will be a hint.

Comment: @dimich The script itself is basically just scraping an email inbox and updating a MySQL database based on the contents. Debugging the script is where I came across this cronjob. The `-O` part specifically is what's throwing me. I saw a YouTube video where it described the `-O` option as just a way to rename a download. I guess I want to know what effect removing the `-O` would have.

Comment: By default wget saves downloaded HTML page or file to local file, i.e. `wget "http://foo.bar.com/file.php"` will save content returned by server to local `file.php`. `-O` (alias `--output-document`) says "save to specified path", so `wget -O /dev/null ...` says "save to /dev/null" which means "don't save at all". Well, in context with e-mail checking and database update it makes sense: probably it notifies server that some new email arrived or database updated or whatever etc. Thus, it's a kind of notification.

Comment: @dimich Ahh ok that makes perfect sense. I guess I had slightly conflated "renaming" to "save it here." Thank you, it's much clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/null` is (pseudo-)device file that just discards everything that's written to it. There's no *renaming* involved there, `wget -O file` just opens the named file (possibly creating it) and writes there. In this case with `/dev/null`, the operating system just discards the written data.

The end result is that the URL in question is requested from the server, whatever scripts involved run on the server side, and the response (if any) is discarded.

Actually *renaming* a file on top of a device node would replace the device node with that file. A regular user can't write to `/dev`, but running e.g. `mv somefile.txt /dev/null` as root could cause some "interesting" effects in the long run.

Without the `-O` option, `wget` would create a file in the current directory named based on the URL, so `file.php` in this case.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the explanation - so what is the specific function of the -O option here? Is it even necessary to grab and run the script?

Comment: @confused_nomad: If the `-O /dev/null` was absent from the command, `wget` would save the contents of the URL to a file in the current directory.

Comment: @jwodder Would removing only the `-O` and not the `/dev/null` have any effect?

Comment: @confused_nomad: Then `wget` would try to treat `/dev/null` as a URL to download from, resulting in an error.

Comment: @confused_nomad, here, `-O` is an option that takes an argument, so the whole `-O /dev/null` part goes together. It could be written as `-O/dev/null`, too.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ok gotcha, that makes sense. Thanks!